CSS Spy not opening in Eclipse
I'm using Eclipse Version: 2024-03 (4.31). I want do some changes to the theme and trying to open CSS Spy, but unable to open it. Rest of the spies, event spy, model spy, css scratchpad etc are opening except for this. How do I fix this issue.

How are you trying to run it? Does it appear in the "Window > Spies" list? Are there any messages in the Error Log?

@greg-449   I'm using Alt+Shft+F5. Yes I do see all the spy list under Window > Spies. No, I do not get any error message. I could see the selection, but the CSS Spy dialog is not opening.

Did you look in the Error Log? That may contain messages even if not error message is displayed.

Warning: NLS missing message: SpyProcessor_category in: org.eclipse.pde.spy.core.messages . This is wat I see in error log

@greg-449 I changed the workspace of the runtime application and it is working now. Not sure why this was happening. Thanks for the help.
